# Replacing multiple cell values on a single code

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on an Excel VBA project which merges data from multiple workbooks and returns the source filename in the Column C.

Thus my Column C will be filled with cell values like `List for Ann.xlsx`, `List for Ben.xlsx` and `List for Sam.xlsx`

I would like to replace the Column C cell values `List for Ann.xlsx to Ann` and similarly for the other file names in Column C.

Is there a single code to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the VBA Replace function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using formulas: Try the following formula in a new column...

```
=MID(C2,10,LEN(C2)-14)
```

If you wish, you can then copy the results back to column C.